# vim, is it possible to add increasing numbers next to words each time the words are repeated in a text?

Tags: vim

Let's assume I have a text file with the following content:

```
ABRADER                 AH B R EY D AH
ABRADER                 AH B R EY D AH R
ABRADERS                AH B R EY D AH Z
ABRADES                 AH B R EY D Z
APRIL                   EY P R AH L
APRIL                   EY P R AH 
APRIL                   EY AH P R AH
```

I would like to execute a vim command that looks for duplicates and adds a counter (inside brackets) in each word that is repeated, but it only checks the first word in each line. In the current example, the resulting text should be:

```
ABRADER                 AH B R EY D AH
ABRADER(2)              AH B R EY D AH R
ABRADERS                AH B R EY D AH Z
ABRADES                 AH B R EY D Z
APRIL                   EY P R AH L
APRIL(2)                EY P R AH 
APRIL(3)                EY AH P R AH
```

Comment: if this line helps? note that the output format is changed. `%!awk 'a[$1]++{$1=$1"("a[$1]")"}7'` but you can re-align them with other plugins.

Comment: thanks Kent, that line seems to work perfectly (a part from the formatting as you said), what does 7' mean?

Comment: awk take non-zero number as default action: `{print}` so `7` will print the line. I would post it as an answer, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pure Vim solution, modeled after @Kent's `awk` solution (oneliner split here over multiple lines for readability):

```
let d = {} |
\   global/^\S/
\       let cw = expand('<cword>') |
\       let d[cw] = get(d, cw, 0) + 1 |
\       if d[cw] > 1 |
\           execute 'normal! elgR(' . d[cw] . ')' |
\       endif
```

It counts the occurrences of the first word (`<cword>`; `:global` puts the cursor at the beginning of each non-empty line (`^\S`)), and uses `gR` to append the count without affecting the existing alignment.

Comment: This seems to work almost perfectly too, the formatting is perfect but the number inside brackets is separated from the word by one space, how do I attach the number on brackets to the corresponding word? (vim super-beginner)

Comment: That's encoded in the `ell` motion: to end of first word, two to the right. I've changed that to `el` to match your requirements.

Comment: now it looks like it's working perfectly, thanks Ingo

Answer (score 3):

This turned to the external `awk` to do the job. The format could be mess (the number of spaces) after the command was executed. But it will give you the count of occurrences in required format.

```
%!awk 'a[$1]++{$1=$1"("a[$1]")"}7'
```

The alignment could be fulfilled by other plugin or vim-fu, if you like it could be done by awk as well, but the codes would be longer than the above one.